# What to do after getting new upload key of google play store?

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I developed and deployed an app on play store from my previous laptop. But now, I have changed my laptop but now I'm unable to upload the updated version of that app. I requested the new app signing key from google. Even, after that I'm getting the same error.

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. 
Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. 
Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
```

I want to ask what should I do after receiving new upload key.